# Add CSS from codemyui to Button on wordpress site

Tags: css, button

I would like to add to add this css example to my button on my website

https://codemyui.com/ghost-button-glint-effect-3d-button/

I already tried pasting the css code in the wordpress customizer add css input...

I adjusted the class to my button....

.btn--primary

but it doesn't work

hope anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you include all the css that Jessica wrote? Here is her codepen example: https://codepen.io/bigglesrocks/pen/RPzNjw?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sheen {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(0);
            transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(12.5em);
            transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(12.5em);
  }
}
@keyframes sheen {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(0);
            transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(12.5em);
            transform: skewY(-45deg) translateX(12.5em);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2194E0;
  border: 2px solid #2194E0;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 3em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -4.5em;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg) translateX(0);
          transform: skewX(-45deg) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #2194E0;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1977b5;
}
.button:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg) translateX(13.5em);
          transform: skewX(-45deg) translateX(13.5em);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="button">Shiney!</a>
</div>
```

I managed to get this integrated in my WordPress installation. Try using the !important tag incase there are some predefined classes in your template.